# VS Code formatting plugins

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting

Is there a way in VS Code to format code according to the style that a person prefers? I guess there might be a plugin for this sort of thing but I've not found that.

For example, I prefer 'K&R' coding style while a colleague prefers 'Whitesmiths' style. When we share code or functions it would be nice to autoformat code into the style that each prefers.

This does not seem like it should be so difficult for a plugin to do except that coding style also has to parse the language of the code, so Whitesmiths PowerShell is going to be different from Whitesmiths on Perl I would imagine.

Are there any plugins like this (or internal functionality in VS Code - it's a very comprehensive tool without installing any plugins of course!) that people use regularly like this?

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to its name, "JIndent" (commercial) is a tool I've been using for the exact purpose you're asking about.